# Convert the mysql table details to an Excel (.xls) or comma separated file (.csv) using Python

Tags: python, mysql, file, csv, xlwt

I want to convert the mysql database table contents to an Excel(.xls) or comma separated file(csv) using python script... Is it possible? Any one can help me?

Thanks in advance,
Nimmy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With third-party project [mysqldb](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/) installed you can easily read that table, e.g:

```
import MySQLdb
conn = MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost",
                        user = "testuser",
                        passwd = "testpass",
                        db = "test")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM thetable")
while True:
   row = cursor.fetchone()
   if row is None: break
   # here: do something with the row
```

You can of course write each row to a `csv` file with Python's standard library [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#module-csv) module -- you'll just need an `import csv` at the start of your code.  Then, after the `cursor.execute`, you can use code such as:

```
with open('thefile.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    while True:
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        if row is None: break
        writer.writerow(row)
```

If you want to write to an `.xls` file instead of a `.csv`, see third-party module [xlwt](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt/).

Comment: Edited URL for xlwt to remove antique version number -- default is  latest version which saves wear and tear on the support team :-)